# how create a shopping cart rule buy 1 prod A and 1 prod B, receive free 1 prod c?

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, grouped-products, free-shipping, ce-1.9.2.2, free-gift

Hi for holiday i do create a grouped product and i need create a rule for add a free product when the order include the group. how the rules don't works for group directly  i thing the rule

If (buy 1 product A and 1 Product B) receive 1 Product C and free shipping

I control extra the min total amount( = to grouped total) and if the product are deleted.

[image: Conditions]

[image: Actions]

This produce the effect, if the customer take the group product, but if a client buy one of sku and more than total bypass the rule.

exist a way to write this order or is better start to write a extension to add group products to shopping rules?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correct, your problem is in this part

> SKU **is one of** **AB0027, AB0049**

Instead you should split the condition into two conditions, one for each SKU and change the total amount accordingly.

For example if the grouped product is 15x AB0027 + 15x AB0049, it's

> if **ALL** of these conditions are **TRUE**
>
> - if  **total amount equals or greater than 15** for a subselection of items in the cart matching **ALL**  these conditions
>
>   - Qty in cart **equals or greater than 1**
>   - SKU **is equal to AB0027**
> - if  **total amount equals or greater than 15** for a subselection of items in the cart matching **ALL**  these conditions
>
>   - Qty in cart **equals or greater than 1**
>   - SKU **is equal to AB0049**